# Date Format - How to add 'n' hours to the current time in php?

Tags: php, date, time

I get current time:

```
$today = time();
$date = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today));
```

How do I add 5 hours to the current time?

Comment: the dupe is a little dated should really be using http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$today = time();
date('h:i:s A', strtotime('+5 hours'), $today);
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will parse any textual datetime description in English.

Comment: Thank you, heres what I tried and its working :)    $today = date('m/d/y');
$addhours = 18000;
$date2 = date('h:i:s A', strtotime($today)+$addhours);
echo $date2;

Comment: Glad to hear! You can learn more about `strtotime` by reading the topics above marked as duplicated. You can accept the answer as well.