# wrong result after date_default_timezone_set

Tags: php, datetime

i want to some time calculation with this code:

```
$timestamp = mt_rand(1, 2147385600);
$oldDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-6 hour", (floor(strtotime($oldDate) / 6 / 60 / 60) * 6 * 60 * 60)));
echo $oldDate . " - " . $date;
```

i want to calculate exact previous time period (6 hours) of given time not included itself. for example:

```
2001-10-23 07:56:28 -> 2001-10-23 00:00:00 to 2001-10-23 05:59:59
2037-01-31 01:31:25 -> 2037-01-30 18:00:00 to 2037-01-30 23:59:59
```

this code working very well. but when i added `date_default_timezone_set`, result becomes wrong.

how does `date_default_timezone_set` break the calculations? how can i solve this?

i added a link with working and non working sample. pleasse check this out:
http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/32ug-7w4y please click `run-f9` a few times.

Comment: what is your `date_default_timezone` ? and it should be `hours` instead of `hour`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Format - How to add 'n' hours to the current time in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779306/date-format-how-to-add-n-hours-to-the-current-time-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add 'x' number of hours to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386308/add-x-number-of-hours-to-date)

Comment: @Gulshan
`date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Istanbul');`

Comment: none of link my answer.

Comment: i just discovered that it works correctly with `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')`

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/32ug-7w4y
please check this out. i want utc version.

Comment: @mbunal its caused of `day light saving`  here is a link which can help you to prevent this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698779/timezone-with-dst-handling-by-php

Answer (score 0):

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/931q-48kk 
my simple solution:

```
<pre>
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Istanbul');
$t = mt_rand(1, 2247385600);
$saat = date("H", $t);
if ($saat>=0 && $saat<6)
{
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
    $t = strtotime("-1 day", $t);
    $ilk = date("Y-m-d 18:00:00", $t);
    $t = strtotime("+5 hour 59 minute 59 second", strtotime($ilk));
    $son = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
}
elseif ($saat>=6 && $saat<12)
{
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
    $ilk = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", $t);
    $t = strtotime("+5 hour 59 minute 59 second", strtotime($ilk));
    $son = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
}
elseif ($saat>=12 && $saat<18)
{
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
    $ilk = date("Y-m-d 06:00:00", $t);
    $t = strtotime("+5 hour 59 minute 59 second", strtotime($ilk));
    $son = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
}
else
{
    $now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
    $ilk = date("Y-m-d 12:00:00", $t);
    $t = strtotime("+5 hour 59 minute 59 second", strtotime($ilk));
    $son = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t);
}
echo $now . " => " . $ilk . " - ". $son;
?>
</pre>
```

now, the script populate data from `$ilk` to `$son`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the DateTime extension [**dt**](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) you can do that

```
<?php
require '/yourpath/class.dt.php';

date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");  //or others

$dtStart = dt::create('2001-10-23 07:56:28')
  ->cut("6 hours")
  ->modify("-6 hours")
; 
echo $dtStart->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //2001-10-23 00:00:00

$dtEnd = dt::create('2001-10-23 07:56:28')
  ->cut("6 hours")
  ->modify("-1 Second")
; //2001-10-23 05:59:59
echo $dtEnd->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //2001-10-23 05:59:59
```